# Can I receive security updates without upgrading from KitKat to Lollipop?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, security, 5.1-lollipop

I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab S tablet, and it's currently running the stock Android 4.4.2. A friend of mine had her Galaxy S5 upgraded to Lollipop, and i personally don't like the way it looks, especially with no dark theme available. So i simply ignore the software update notifications my tablet keeps giving me, since they also promise me that upgrade to Lollipop.

Considering the yesterday's [statement](http://blog.zimperium.com/experts-found-a-unicorn-in-the-heart-of-android/) from Zimperuim about a critical vulnerability in the Stagefright library, I'm really concerned about getting a security update for it when it comes, but still I really don't want to jump onto Lollipop for the sake of it.

So does anybody have an idea how to stay on KitKat while keeping the security up-to-date?

Comment: Best way to keep secure is installing updates. Refusing to do so keeps you in a circle, you want security updates but don't want updates.

Comment: I doubt that very much (edit: targeting the question, not the previous comment posted almost similar to mine). If Samsung already has rolled-out a higher Android version for that device, they won't support the lower version with "security updates" anymore. Feel free to ask their support, though – they are more likely to know than we ;)

Comment: @xangua, in the PC world, one doesn't have to get the latest version of the OS to get the security updates. It's enough to have the version that's still supported. Are you suggesting that it's not true for KitKat?

Comment: @Izzy, thanks for suggesting that it might be a vendor-specific thing.

Comment: Not the PC world here, you'd probably have better luck with a custom rom either because you want to stick with kitkat (cyanogenmod will provide a bugfix for their kitkat build) or because you lack of a dark theme (lollipop CM build has a theme engine).

Comment: @xangua, another great suggestion, thank you.

Comment: @Semisonic Not just vendor specific (though with most vendors you can be lucky if you receive updates at all a year after the device rolled out). It's simply to cost intensive for them. Btw one reason Google tries to out-source components of the OS to separate packages which you can update via their Playstore, as it was done e.g. with the webview browser component. But that doesn't work for everything (though it should at least for Hangouts, with the current "big MMS thing").